# NPM, package.json and supporting multiple major version of a third party library, testing each version?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, npm-install, semantic-versioning

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "devDependencies": {
    "3d-party": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Imagine that `my-library` should support `3.x` and `4.x` version of `3d-party` package. `my-library` is well tested.

Is there something that I can run locally, like Travis CI, that:

- Run `npm install`, requiring a specific version at time (`3.x` and `4.x`)
- Run my test to ensure that `my-library` works with both version

Answer (score 0):

youd have to dupe the package.json and change the `3rd-party` version to a specific version - then run `npm install`

make sure to remove the `^` as that signifies - `get latest version`

so you should do `"3d-party": "3.5.5"`

to automate this you can use `gulp` and create a project folder for each 3rd party dep with its own specific package.json

then you write a gulp build that dupes your source into each folder and runs npm install

you can then run each version and see if it crashes :)

Comment: Hope there is an automated way?

Comment: you can automate it with GULP